# Link state routing protocol - Dijkstras Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, networking, network-protocols, router, dijkstra

[image]

N- Network
R- Router

In the above picture, you can see a question about link state routing protocol. When you are doing the **Dijkstra algorithm for R3** for this, I know you start off by adding N3 and N4 then look at the cost, 2 is less than 4 so N4 becomes permanent but when N4 becomes permanent does it add R4 and R7 or do you just pick one of them?

Comment: Neither N4, nor N3 have an outgoing edge, so are these paths undirected? Also, I guess you start from R3, where are you trying to reach?

Answer (score 0):

This example is a little confusing, because of the arrow heads, but I guess we can just assume that this is an undirected graph with vertex set `N union R`.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm), these are the steps of Dijkstra's:

1. Assign to every node a tentative distance value: set it to zero for our initial node and to infinity for all other nodes.
2. Mark all nodes unvisited. Set the initial node as current. Create a set of the unvisited nodes called the unvisited set consisting of all the nodes except the initial node.
3. For the current node, consider all of its unvisited neighbors and calculate their tentative distances.
4. When we are done considering all of the neighbors of the current node, mark the current node as visited and remove it from the unvisited set. A visited node will never be checked again.
5. If the destination node has been marked visited (when planning a route between two specific nodes) or if the smallest tentative distance among the nodes in the unvisited set is infinity (when planning a complete traversal), then stop. The algorithm has finished.
6. Select the unvisited node that is marked with the smallest tentative distance, and set it as the new "current node" then go back to step 3.

Let's look at these steps for your case.

- Ad1. `R3` is the initial node, so it gets distance `0`.
- Ad2. `R3` is current.
- Ad3. Visit `N3` and `N4` and set their tentative distances to `4` and `2`, respectively.
- Ad4. Mark `R3` as done.
- Ad5. --
- Ad6. Select `N4` as current node and go back to step 3.
- Ad3. Visit `R4` and `R7` and set their tentative distances to `6` and `3`, respectively.
- Ad4. Mark `N4` as done.
- Ad5. --
- Ad6. Select `R7` as current node and go back to step 3.

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing about Dijkstra's algorithm is that you never discard a node until you process it.

```
Step 1 : R3
N4 - 2
N3 - 4

Step 2 : N4
R7 - 3
N3 - 4
R4 - 6

Step 3 : R7
N3 - 4
R4 - 6
N6 - 9
```

At this step you have N3 as the closest with R3 that is left, so you do N3

```
Step 4 : N3
R4 - 6
R8 - 6
R2 - 6
N6 - 9
```

Note that after every step there is a sort. So a minimum priority queue should help.